# How to initialize Flowplayer HTML5 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, flowplayer

I am building an html page with a player. I get the video url and cover url by a remote service. I would know if it is possible (and how to do) to initialize the flowplayer in javascript without change with jquery the url and the cover about the video

```
 <div class="flowplayer" id="modern" data-key="" style="display:none;  background: #000 url(cover.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size: cover;"
 data-swf="lib/flowplayer5.5.2/flowplayer.swf"
 data-advance="false">
     **<video id="video" controls>
           <source id="videoSource" type="video/mp4"src="video.mp4">
     </video> </div>**
```

**I did this:**

```
$("#player").flowplayer({

                        swf:'lib/flowplayer5.5.2/flowplayer.swf', 
                         splash: true,
                         ratio: 9/16,
                         clip: {
                           sources: [
                              { type: "video/mp4",
                                src:  url }
                            ]
                          }
                        });
```

> I obtain this error: Cannot read property 'initialSources' of null

Comment: does it help you ? : https://flowplayer.org/forum/#!/setup#error-is-thrown-when-playli

Comment: Hummm no...If I use the flowplayer 6 it works but with the flowplayer 5 it doen't work...;(